# Extract from array with json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
{
"line1": 12,
"line2": 4,
"line3": 66,
"line4": false,
"line5": true,
"line6": [
    {
        "line7": "false",
        "line8": "true"
    },
    {
        "line9": "false",
        "line10": "false"
    }
],
"line11": 0,
"line12": 0,
```

Using json_decode, I can extract elements from array with the following method:

> $showline1 = $obj->line1;
>
> $showline2 = $obj->line2;

But how to extract line7, line8, line9 and line10? I tried using:

> $showline7 = $obj->line6->line7;
> But it didn't worked.

Comment: Try json_decode(string, true) which will return you an Associative Array instead of Object.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at closely the "line6" has more than one elements inside, So basically you will get array when you decode by json_decode. In Short  to get line7 you need to use $data->line6[0]. To get all inside elements you need to use loop obviously.

Answer (score 0):

line6 is an array so you need target index 
try

```
$showline7 = $obj->line6[0]->line7;
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: How about if line9 and 10 have dynamic names? How can I get those? Can I use: $showline7 = $obj->line6[1]->line9; ?

Comment: $showline7 = $obj->line6[1]->line9; will work for your current object.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
json_decode($your_json_string,true);
```

This will return an array instead of object, and you can get line7 value like this:

```
$obj["line6"][0]["line7"]
```

Or as your object, you can get line7 value like this:

```
$obj->line6[0]->line7
```

Comment: I'm trying to get line9 and 10 now, but it doesn't work. I tried: $obj->line6[1]->line9;

Answer (score 0):

I hve to add another answer here, because the code is long.

This is my test, and it works fine. Please take a look.

```
<?php
$data=json_decode('{
"line1": 12,
"line2": 4,
"line3": 66,
"line4": false,
"line5": true,
"line6": [
    {
        "line7": "false",
        "line8": "true"
    },
    {
        "line9": "false",
        "line10": "false"
    }
],
"line11": 0,
"line12": 0}');
echo $data->line6[1]->line9;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but now it works. Thanks everyone! :D